# Input/output in fasm using in,out commands

Tags: assembly, fasm

I'm starting to learn assembler, and in fasm's documentation there are two commands for input&output - `in`&`out`. As I know, the stdin is port #0, and stdout - #1, so I try to run this code:

```
in eax,0
```

but the program crashes. The same result after running

```
out 1,eax
```

I tried to search smth about this, but no luck.

So, what is the right usage of in&out commands, and is there a simpler way to do input/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are hardware ports. A special x86 hardware method of reading and writing to the peripheral devices. `in` and `out` instructions, form special signals to the CPU buses, that the peripherals can understand.

In order to read and write to STDIN and STDOUT you must use the standard file functions on your OS, passing STDIN, respectively STDOUT as a file handle.

For Linux these are sys_read and sys_write system functions. You can read an extensive, assembly-centric system calls reference [here](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/lscr).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing some things.

The commands `in` and `out` are used to read from a port and to write to a port respectively. These ports have nothing to do with STDIN or STDOUT. (At the DOS level STDIN is 1 and STDOUT is 2.)

Ports are byte sized by design, but you can read/write multiple ports at once.
When you wrote `in eax,0` the CPU got 4 bytes coming from ports 0, 1, 2, and 3.
When you wrote `out 1,eax` the CPU put 4 bytes into the ports 1, 2, 3, and 4.

The ports that you used here service the *first DMA controller*. You should not tamper with these settings!